# Removing var from a function

Tags: scala

I have the following function in scala

```
def pathToBeRedacted(p: Path, redactProperty: Int): Seq[Vertex] = {

    var seq = Seq.empty[Vertex]
    val l = p.objects()

    val r = createVertexFromPath(l, redactProperty)
    r match {
      case Some(x) => seq :+= x
      case None =>
    }
    seq

  }
```

Its being called  as

```
path.map(x => pathToBeRedacted(x, 2)).flatten
```

How can I get rid of the var and still add it values to the sequence ?

Comment: `path.flatMap(p => createVertexFromPath(p.objects(), 2))`

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are returning an at-most-one-element `Seq`, 
so you might as well do this:

```
def pathToBeRedacted(p: Path, redactProperty: Int): Seq[Vertex] = {
  createVertexFromPath(p.objects(), redactProperty).toSeq
}
```

This works because `Option` is implicitly convertible to `Iterable`, and `Iterable` has a `toSeq`.

---

If you want to keep the solution closer to your code and only eliminate the var, then you can return the result of `match` directly:

```
def pathToBeRedacted(p: Path, redactProperty: Int): Seq[Vertex] = {

  val seq = Seq.empty[Vertex]
  val l = p.objects()

  val r = createVertexFromPath(l, redactProperty)
  r match {
    case Some(x) => seq :+ x
    case None => seq
  }

}
```